# Unable to disable https methods on Apache-2.4.7

Tags: 14.04, apache2, authentication, https

I have `Ubuntu-14.04` system with installed `apache-2.4.7 Server built: May 9-2017` web server and created the one the https based virtualhost with htpass, I wish to disable https methods like DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE etc. Following method i tried but not working.

First Method used:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Second Method used:

```
<LimitExcept POST DELETE>
    deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

I'm monitor on `https://www.htbridge.com`, In which showing all http method allow !

Anybody have idea about this ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what HTTPS has to do here. Do you mean you want to disable the methods only on HTTPS but not HTTP?

Comment: @Dan Only `HTTPS` protocal enable for this virtualhost.

Comment: @Ravi not an expert but first `TRACE` limit is done thus: `TraceEnable [on|off|extended]`,

Comment: @George currently `TraceEnable Off` on security.conf

Comment: @George I'm using `Index of /` page, So that not able to disable http method ?